# Getting numpy vector from a trained Doc2Vec model for each document

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

This is my first time using Doc2Vec
I'm trying to classify works of an author. I have trained a model with Labeled Sentences (paragraphs, or strings of specified length), with words = the list of words in the paragraph, and tags = author's name. In my case I only have two authors.
I tried accessing the docvecs attribute from the trained model but it only contains two elements, corresponding to the two tags I have when I trained the model. I'm trying to get the doc2vec numpy representations of each paragraph I fed in to the training so I can use that as training data later on. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk training only creates vectors for tags you supplied. If you want to read out a bulk-trained vector per paragraph (as if by `model.docvecs['paragraph000']`), you have to give each paragraph a unique tag during training (like `'paragraph000'`). You can give docs other tags as well - but bulk training only creates remembers doc-vectors for supplied tags.

After training, you can infer vectors for any other texts you supply to `infer_vector()` - and of course you could supply the same paragraphs that were used during training.

Comment: I actually figured that out and I’m using paragraph number as tags as you said. (10000 vectors per author) I do this for both authors and then train a svm model (sklearn) with it. But when I use those numeric docvec arrays as vectors I get horrible accuracy.. ~50%. I got 73% with nltk pos_tag so I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used infer_vector on my paragraphs and am now getting 93.28% accuracy in my binary classification task!! ;)